# Access variable inside function and block

Tags: node.js, function, scope

I am playing around with some nodeJs things, I read about block and functions scooping but I was not able to access my variable `jsonArrayObj`:

```
csv({delimiter: ['   ']})
  .fromFile(csvFilePath)
  .on('end_parsed', function(jsonArrayObj) {
    console.log(jsonArrayObj);
    function cssResult() {
      return jsonArrayObj;
    }
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

console.log('jsonArrayObj'); // I want to print the results here also
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this.

```
csv({delimiter: ['   ']})
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('end_parsed', function(jsonArrayObj) {
 console.log(jsonArrayObj);
 myNewFunc(jsonArrayObj);
 function cssResult() {
  return jsonArrayObj;
 }
})
.on('error', (err)=>{
 console.log(err);
});

var myNewFunc = function(myVar){
  console.log(myVar); // this will be your result
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable jsonArrayObj is just defined on your function's scope. So jsonArrayObj is just accessible in your function.

If you want to use it out of your function, you have to define a variable outside of your function, and then tell your function that this variable takes jsonArrayObj's value.

Like this :

```
 var myRes;
 csv({delimiter: ['   ']})
      .fromFile(csvFilePath)
      .on('end_parsed', function(jsonArrayObj) {
        myRes = jsonArrayObj;
        console.log(jsonArrayObj);
        function cssResult() {
          return jsonArrayObj;
        }
      })
      .on('error', (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      });

    console.log(myRes);
```